# Program keeps crashing when I destroy my linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, destroy

For some reason, my code keeps crashing.
If anyone can help me find out why, I would be very thankful.

```
int destroy(struct node *p)
{
    struct node * temp = p;
    struct node * next;

    while (temp->next != NULL)
    {
        next = temp->next;
        free(temp);
        temp = next;
    }
    p = NULL;

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Maybe `temp` is NULL (it is NULL when you reach the end of the list)...you should be testing `while (temp != NULL)` instead.

Answer (score 4):

You need to test `temp` for null-ness, not `temp->next`:

```
void destroy(struct node *p)
{
    struct node *temp = p;

    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        struct node *next = temp->next;
        free(temp);
        temp = next;
    }
}
```

You also don't need to set `p` to null (it doesn't do anything useful).  And returning a status is not a good idea.  Your callers either have to test it (but will never see anything other than 1, so the test is pointless), or they have to ignore it (in which case, why bother to return it?).  You could do without the variable `temp`, too:

```
void destroy(struct node *list)
{
    while (list != NULL)
    {
        struct node *next = list->next;
        free(list);
        list = next;
    }
}
```

If you really want to set the pointer to null, you have to change the notation:

```
void destroy(struct node **list)
{
    struct node *node = *list;
    while (node != NULL)
    {
        struct node *next = node->next;
        free(node);
        node = next;
    }
    *list = NULL;
}
```

and instead of:

```
struct node *root = ...;
...
destroy(root);
```

you would have to write:

```
struct node *root = ...;
...
destroy(&root);
```

Comment: Thanks that helped. turns out i was having a problem somewhere else as well though :/

Comment: That, unfortunately, is often the case.  We can only diagnose the problems in the code you show, though -- we're good, but we're not omniscient.

Comment: oo of course but I will not post it on here before I spend some time trying to figure it out myself

Comment: Excellent!  That is precisely the correct attitude.  That should probably be  a separate new question, though.